# winforms read from text file using arrays c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, listbox

I am doing winforms, and i am trying to read some lines from a text file so after that i can display it at a listbox. In my winforms i am recording activities and it is writing to a text file.

[image]

When i restart the program it is not displaying the lines. Here's my code to write activities to the text file shown:

```
` private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(User.ID + "activity.txt", true))
            {
                sw.Write(Environment.NewLine + txtName.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Type: " + txtType.Text + Environment.NewLine + "People: " + Convert.ToInt32(txtPeople.Text) + Environment.NewLine + dateTimePicker1.Value + Environment.NewLine);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }`
```

I am trying to display these lines when i open the program in the left listbox and details of it in the right listbox.

[image]

I tried something like that, but it is not displaying the info when the program restarts.

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(User.ID + "activity.txt"))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    evName = sr.ReadLine();
                    evType = sr.ReadLine();
                    evPeople = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                    evDay = DateTime.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

                }
            }
```

Comment: You can add your reading code on the `Form_Load` event so whenever you start your program it will look at the `activity.txt`. Just make sure to add appropriate error handling.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```